# Spring: Post request with InputStreamResource

Tags: spring, spring-web

I have some InputStream and want to do post request using RestTempalte from spring-web.

```
public void postRequest(InputStream in){
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> parameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    parameters.add("file", new InputStreamResource(inputStream) {
        @Override
        public String getFilename(){
            return "some_name";
        }
    });

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(parameters);

    restTemplate.postForEntity(SOME_ENDPOINT, httpEntity, String.class)
}
```

When i invoke this method the IllegalStateException is occurred.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: InputStream has already been read - do not use InputStreamResource if a stream needs to be read multiple times
```

In source code getInputStream() method from InputStreamResource we can see:

```
public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException, IllegalStateException {
    if (this.read) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("InputStream has already been read - " +
                "do not use InputStreamResource if a stream needs to be read multiple times");
    }
    this.read = true;
    return this.inputStream;
}
```

How can i initialize InputStreamResource for my purpose?  What do i miss?

Answer (score 5):

I am resolving it by overriding getContentLenght()

```
public void postRequest(InputStream in){
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> parameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    parameters.add("file", new InputStreamResource(inputStream) {
        @Override
        public String getFilename(){
            return "some_name";
        }

        @Override
        public long contentLength() throws IOException {
            return -1;
        }
    });

   HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(parameters);

   restTemplate.postForEntity(SOME_ENDPOINT, httpEntity, String.class)
}
```

Because native method `contentLength()` invoke `getInputStream()` to calculate length. And when invoke `getInputStream()` second time to take content from stream we get exception.

Comment: It should be said that `ResourceHttpMessageConverter` avoids to call `contentLength()` on `InputStreamResource`s for this reason, but *only* on exact `InputStreamResource` instances, not on instances of subclasses of this class, because it is expect that subclasses can supply a length determined in some way. In this case, you're using an anonymous subclass of `InputStreamResource` and this is why you need to also override `contentLength()`. I had the exact same problem.